# Module is not available after being imported

Tags: powershell

I was using the [WASP](https://wasp.codeplex.com/) PowerShell Module, previously it worked correctly but has now stopped working.

Currently I'm unable to import the module as it seems to be empty. `Get-Command -Module WASP` also returns nothing.

```
Import-Module -Name .\WASP.dll -Force
Get-Module

ModuleType Version    Name                                ExportedCommands
---------- -------    ----                                ----------------
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Management     {Add-Computer, Add-Content, Checkpoint-Computer, Clear-Co
Manifest   3.1.0.0    Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility        {Add-Member, Add-Type, Clear-Variable, Compare-Object...}
Script     1.1        PSReadline                          {Get-PSReadlineKeyHandler, Get-PSReadlineOption, Remove-P
Binary     1.2.0.0    WASP
```

I've downloaded the module again but it did not help (I remember to unlock file after downloading). I'm using Windows 10.

How do I make the module work again?

Powershell version

```
Name                           Value
----                           -----
PSVersion                      5.0.10586.672
PSCompatibleVersions           {1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0...}
BuildVersion                   10.0.10586.672
CLRVersion                     4.0.30319.42000
WSManStackVersion              3.0
PSRemotingProtocolVersion      2.3
SerializationVersion           1.1.0.1
```

Comment: Are you on a 64bit or on a 32bit machine? If you are on a 64bit machine, which version of PowerShell are you running?

Comment: It's 64bit machine. I run powershell using simple 'powershell' command. I always run my script in the same way. I've added ps version to the question.